# How to disable PhpStorm tick and backtick previsualization?

Tags: phpstorm, backticks

I recently got a problem on how the ticks <kbd>´</kbd> and backticks <kbd>`</kbd> are shown.

Usually when I hit <kbd>´</kbd> or <kbd>`</kbd> nothing happens until next key is pressed. This is the expected behavior and other apps work in this way.

For PhpStorm when I hit <kbd>´</kbd> or <kbd>`</kbd> the character appears underlined in the screen waiting for next character like showing a previsualization of the tick.

This is a problem when I what to surround selections because all the text get replaced.

[image]

[image]

**Do you know how to disable this previsualization of the ticks?**

Note: I use international English keyboard.

Comment: No idea from my end. But anyway: 1) what language is that? 2) what is your IDE version and OS? 3) Try disabling all 3rd party plugins (not bundled by default), restart IDE and see if it makes any diff.

Comment: 1) It is JS languaje but this happens for all languages 2) I am using phpstorm and linux 3) already tried but nothing, seems to be only releated with the IDE.

Comment: I have a plain `.js` file with just `text = abcd;` line. If I select `abcd` and hit `\`` it will surround the text with backtick for me. To have a similar behaviour (no surround but insert just single `\`` and delete selected text) I would need to disable 2 options at `Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Smart Keys`. Please show what you have got there. P.S. I'm on Windows 10, 2020.3.3, English (UK) keyboard.

Comment: I tried already each of the smart keys configuration. It seems related on how the editor display modifier keys like ticks ´ `, dieresis  ¨ or the Alt key that also when pressed appears a weird character underlined. All of them are shown before next key is pressed to modify the input

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be this one (despite it being described as a macOS-specific issue): https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-235878

The only workaround at the moment is not using international keyboard layouts and sticking to the usual ones.

Comment: Indeed changing the keyboard layout is a workaround but not quite what I am looking for. I also see any key modifier is also written, like when I press Alt, a weird character shows in the screen also underlined waiting for more keys to be pressed.

Comment: It's also the case for other editors, the only difference is that they don't have the "wrap in symbol" function, so you don't usually type symbols over a selected line.
You can try using RAlt+Backtick, it's supposed to output the backtick right away